# How can I adjust my wifi settings?

Tags: wireless

It seems that my

```
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
```

Is only operating at **"b"** speeds.  How can I kick it up a notch to **"N"**

I just added a TrendNet TEW-731BR to my home network and would really like to get quicker than 72Mb/s

Thanks

(figured out that my module name is rtl8192ce. Now looking for a configuration file.)

To save everyone else time:  This thread:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604101&page=1  is pretty useless if you already have the realtek driver installed and working at all.

Another suggestion, that of setting the AP to only "N" mode.  has made no difference in bit rate, still 72Mb/s

Comment: have you looked at this approach?
http://mikebeach.org/2011/04/06/ubuntu-and-wireless-n-speed-issues/

Comment: Well, that is a different driver, but let me see if I can find a proper name

Comment: (module, not driver)

Comment: Well, that wasn't a good idea.  I just uninstalled my wifi driver. And just a make/make install cycle isn't restarting it.

(Rebooting after the make install fixed it.)

Comment: I had the same wifi card in my laptop and I had the same problem.  I searched Google and there were dozens of websites with people complaining about that card and solutions that never worked for me. In the end I ended up buying an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 wifi card off of Ebay for $15 and it worked fine. If your time is worth money to you then I suggest upgrading to a better wifi card.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like this isn't the wifi card or driver, it's the AP.  I changed to a different one on the same network and boom 150Mb/s   Of course this Trendnet should be able to do 300Mb/s.  so that isn't entirely solved, but until I see at least 150 out of it, I am blaming the AP.